# Print multiple instance of a table in query on SQL server doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute this query on my c# application, linked with SQL Server.
This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(1) pil1.nome, pil1.cognome, pil1.scuderia, pil2.nome, pil2.cognome, pil2.scuderia, p1.punteggio AS punteggio1, p2.punteggio AS punteggio2, (p1.punteggio+p2.punteggio) AS punteggio_tot 
                          FROM pilota pil1, pilota pil2,  punti p1, punti p2
                                                               WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *                                                                                           
FROM risultato r1, risultato r2                                                                                 
WHERE r1.pilota < r2.pilota                                                                                       
AND r1.posizione = p1.posizione                                                                                   
AND r2.posizione = p2.posizione                                                                                   
AND r1.data_gran_premio = @date                                                                                   
AND r2.data_gran_premio = @date                                                                                    
AND r1.pilota = pil1.codice                                                                                       
AND r2.pilota = pil2.codice)                                                                                      
AND pil1.scuderia = pil2.scuderia                                                                                 
AND pil1.codice <> pil2.codice                                                                                   
GROUP BY pil1.nome, pil2.nome, pil1.cognome, pil1.scuderia, pil2.cognome, pil2.scuderia, p1.punteggio, p2.punteggio
ORDER BY punteggio_tot ASC
```

The query is working properly cause I already checked it on workbrench and the output was correct, number and name of columns as well (to check it on workbrench i just changed TOP(1) in LIMIT 1).

But when I execute it on my application the name of the columns are different and the output is incomplete.

WORKBRECH OUTPUT: (correct)
[image: WORKBRECH OUTPUT: (correct)]

SQL Server/ VISUAL STUDIO OUTPUT:
[image: SQL Server/ VISUAL STUDIO OUTPUT:]

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: To add to Gordon's points: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: In general, use of TOP without an ORDER BY clause is logically wrong. In this situation, the database engine is free to return any row that is generated by your query. It might appear to consistently return THE row you desire, but that is just luck. Translating between sql dialects/engines is not quite as simply as you might think.